# What is the difference between flatmap and switchmap in RxJava?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

The [rxjava doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables) definition of switchmap is rather vague and it links to the [same page](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) as flatmap. What is the difference between the two operators?

Comment: About *it links to the same page as flatmap*. It is really true. But scroll down to the *Language-Specific Information* section and open interesting operator. I think this should be done automatically from TOC, but... Also you can see the same picture in [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchMap(rx.functions.Func1)).

Answer (score 202, accepted):

According to the documentation ( http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html )

the `switchMap` is like the `flatMap`, **but** it will only emit items from the new observable until a new event is emitted from the source observable.

The marble diagram shows it well.
Notice the difference in the diagrams:

In `switchMap` the second *original* emission (*green marble*) does not emit its second *mapped* emission (*green square*), since the third *original* emission (*blue marble*) has begun and already emitted its first *mapped* emission (*blue diamond*). In other words, only the **first** of two *mapped* green emissions happens; no green square is emitted because the blue diamond beat it.

In `flatMap`, all mapped results will be emitted, even if they're "stale". In other words, **both** first *and* second of the *mapped* green emissions happen -- a *green square* would've been emitted (if they used consistent map function; since they did not, you see the *second* green diamond, even though it is emitted *after* the *first* blue diamond)

**switchMap**
[image: in switchMap if the original observable emits something new, previous emissions no longer produce mapped observables; this is an effective way to avoid stale results]

**flatMap**

[image: in switchMap if the original observable emits something new, previous emissions no longer produce mapped observables; this is an effective way to avoi stale results]

Comment: Thanks, the diagram is very helpful. Do you know a real world example where switchMap would be used?

Comment: @JulianGo there's an example here: https://github.com/samuelgruetter/rx-playground/blob/master/RxScalaPaint/src/main/scala/Paint.scala#L36 It uses `.map(func).switch`, but that's the same as `.switchMap(func)`.

Comment: OK, it seems one use case is to be able to switch to a backup emitter when the main emitter is down.

Comment: Just in case someone still need a real world example of switchMap, he can follow this link [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#routing-module) and it will understand when to use swicthMap instead of flatMap.

Comment: For an example using SwitchMap from Ben Lesh using RxJs5 - see minutes 25-26 here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE  for me, flatmap was already understood...

Comment: The marble diagram shows it well?  What?  I guess if you already understand switchmap maybe.

Comment: fantastic diagram. I spent half hour reading over the docs. And it took only 2 mins to understand once I cam across this diagram.

Comment: The marble diagram says:  the switchmap example has overlapping observables emitting and, if a new observable emission starts because you requested it, anything that it beats out that is already emitting will be considered 'stale' and not emitted.  flatmap just keeps emitting.

Comment: The real-life example in the video is an interval that keeps firing and there are some observables that error out and die.  The switchmap stays alive to listen for the next one if you have a catch, which is not the same as the overlap in the diagram. I guess you have to have concurrent observables firing and a need to get only the winning emissions in terms of speed.

Comment: One notable thing about switch map is that it also unsubscribes from the observable if it's not selected. It has a very interesting effect in Angular where unsubscribing from and HttpClient cold observable will cancel the underlying request. It can be very interesting when you don't want your browser/and your servers to waste more resources on useless requests.

Comment: I have no idea why people have posted an Angular and Scala example of a switchMap whenever this is an RxJava question

Comment: Could you please add the links to the diagrams in your post. I can only find the flatmap example...

Comment: @PostImpatica lol I've been studying reactivity for some years now... designing my own system, and I've never understood the marble diagram.
A switchMap is composed of 3 sources/branches, the main source/branch, the mutable branch and the resulting branch... instead the diagram shows 2 parallel lines.
Also, in my mind nodes should be representative of allocated state, not of data historical versions.
Overall, this is a very complex system, so complex, that if a new diagram explaining its inner workings were to be developed, you'd need to learn the definitions and syntax imposed by this ...

Comment: diagram... even if you fully understand how the system works in an empirical way.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. SwitchMap retains the result of the latest observable, discarding the previous ones.

Answer (score 184):

I came across this when implementing "instant search" - i.e. when user types in a text box, and results appear in near real-time with each key stroke. The solution seems to be:

1. Have a subject, such as PublishSubject of String
2. In the text box change callback, invoke .onNext(text)
3. apply .debounce filter to rate limit server queries
4. apply .switchMap to perform a server query - taking search term and returning Observable of SearchResponse
5. apply .subscribe with a method that consumes SearchResponse and updates the UI.

With flatMap, the search results could be stale, because search responses may come back out of order. To fix this, switchMap should be used, since it ensures that an old observable is unsubscribed once a newer one is provided.

So, in summary, flatMap should be used when all results matter, regardless of their timing, and switchMap should be used when only results from the last Observable matter.

Comment: You can check [this example in GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/JurassicPad/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thedeveloperworldisyours/jurassicpad/main/MainPresenter.java)

Answer (score 104):

No flatMap discussion is complete without comparing and contrasting with `switchMap`, `concatMap` and `concatMapEager`.

All of these methods take a `Func1` that transform the stream into `Observable`s which are then emitted; the difference is when the returned `Observable`s are subscribed and unsubscribed to, and if and when those the emissions of those `Observable`s are emitted by the `____Map` operator in question.

- `flatMap` subscribes to as many emitted `Observable`s as possible. (It is a platform dependant number. e.g. a lower number on Android) Use this when order is NOT important, and you want emissions ASAP.
- `concatMap` subscribes to the first `Observable` and only subscribes to the next `Observable` when the previous one has completed. Use this when order is important and you want to conserve resources. A perfect example is deferring a network call by checking the cache first. That may typically be followed by a `.first()` or `.takeFirst()` to avoid doing unnecessary work.

  http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/
- `concatMapEager` works much the same but subscribes to as many as possible (platform dependant) but will only emit once the previous `Observable` has completed. Perfect when you have a lot of parallel-processing that needs to be done, but (unlike flatMap) you want to maintain the original order.
- `switchMap` will subscribe to the last `Observable` it encounters and unsubscribe from all previous `Observable`s. This is perfect for cases like search-suggestions: once a user has changed their search query, the old request is no longer of any interest, so it is unsubscribed, and a well behaved Api end-point will cancel the network request.

If you are returning `Observable`s that don't `subscribeOn` another thread, all of the above methods may behave much the same. The interesting, and useful behaviour emerges when you allow the nested `Observable`s to act on their own threads. Then you can get get a lot of benefits from parallel processing, and intelligently unsubscribing or not subscribing from `Observable`s that don't interest your `Subscriber`s

- `amb` may also be of interest. Given any number of `Observable`s it emits the same items that the first `Observable` to emit anything emits.
  That could be useful when you have multiple sources that could/should return the same thing and you want performance. e.g. sorting, you might `amb` a quick-sort with a merge-sort and use whichever was faster.

Comment: `If you are returning Observables that don't subscribeOn another thread, all of the above methods may behave much the same.` - every explanation of `switchMap vs flatMap` I encountered before, missed this important aspect, now everything is clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 62):

**switchMap** [was once called](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/2b707faa5acf9245eb71e8529ba04b2a0d98ecd6/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed) **flatMapLatest** in RxJS 4.

It basically just passes on the events from the **latest** Observable and unsubscribes from the previous one.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Although it is inconsistent with combineLatest, which emits the latest values whenever a source observable emits (not emits once).

Comment: Partly the reason it's called switchMap is because you can implement this operator yourself by using o.map(...).switch(). Though then I would imagine it'd be mapSwitch, which doesn't seem to roll off the tongue so easily.

Answer (score 15):

**Map, FlatMap, ConcatMap** and **SwitchMap** applies a function or modifies the data emitted by an Observable.

- **Map** modifies each item emitted by a source Observable and emits the modified item.
- **FlatMap, SwitchMap** and **ConcatMap** also applies a function on each emitted item but instead of returning the modified item, it returns the Observable itself which can emit data again.
- **FlatMap** and **ConcatMap** work is pretty much same. They merge items emitted by multiple Observables and returns a single Observable.
- The difference between **FlatMap** and **ConcatMap** is the order in which the items are emitted.
- **FlatMap** can interleave items while emitting i.e the emitted items order is not maintained.
- **ConcatMap** preserves the order of items. But the main disadvantage of ConcatMap is, it has to wait for each Observable to complete its work thus asynchronous is not maintained.
- **SwitchMap** is a bit different from **FlatMap** and **ConcatMap**. **SwitchMap** unsubscribes from the previous source Observable whenever new item started emitting, thus always emitting the items from current Observable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the one more - 101 line long [example](https://github.com/Sergey80/rx-java-samples/blob/1ea55f94633617432f4c01b9c9d172ec230a8e82/src/main/java/samples/SwitchMapTest.java). That explains the thing for me.

Like was said: it gets the last observable (the slowest one if you will) and ignores the rest.

As a result:

```
Time | scheduler | state
----------------------------
0    | main      | Starting
84   | main      | Created
103  | main      | Subscribed
118  | Sched-C-0 | Going to emmit: A
119  | Sched-C-1 | Going to emmit: B
119  | Sched-C-0 | Sleep for 1 seconds for A
119  | Sched-C-1 | Sleep for 2 seconds for B
1123 | Sched-C-0 | Emitted (A) in 1000 milliseconds
2122 | Sched-C-1 | Emitted (B) in 2000 milliseconds
2128 | Sched-C-1 | Got B processed
2128 | Sched-C-1 | Completed
```

You see the A got ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re looking for an example code

```java
/**
 * We switch from original item to a new observable just using switchMap.
 * It´s a way to replace the Observable instead just the item as map does
 * Emitted:Person{name='Pablo', age=0, sex='no_sex'}
 */
@Test
public void testSwitchMap() {
    Observable.just(new Person("Pablo", 34, "male"))
              .switchMap(person -> Observable.just(new Person("Pablo", 0, "no_sex")))
              .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: But you miss the key feature of switchMap that distinguishes it from flatMap - only the most recent Observable matters, while unsubscribing from the previous ones.

Comment: In this example, when you replace `switchMap` with `flatMap` it will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Code example

```java
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class SwitchMapTest {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Test
    public void main() throws InterruptedException {
        log("main thread");
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        var disposable = Observable
                .create(emitter -> {
                    IntStream.range(0, 4)
                            .peek(i -> {
                                log("sleep emit");
                                sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1);
                            })
                            .forEach(emitter::onNext);
                    emitter.onComplete();
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .switchMap(o ->
                        Observable.create(emitter -> {
                                    IntStream.range(0, 2).forEach(value -> {
                                        log("sleep switch");
                                        sleep(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 900);
                                        emitter.onNext("original " + o + " | switchMap " + value);
                                    });
                                    emitter.onComplete();
                                })
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
                                    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                                    thread.setDaemon(true);
                                    return thread;
                                })))
                )
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(this::log, throwable -> logger.throwing(throwable), () -> {
                    log("complete");
                    latch.countDown();
                });
        boolean await = latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertTrue(await);
        disposable.dispose();
    }

    private void sleep(@NotNull TimeUnit timeUnit, int timeout) {
        try {
            timeUnit.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    void log(Object message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```xml
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-8r %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-32t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Console

```
720      21:44:46.566 [Test worker                     ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - main thread
787      21:44:46.633 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1       ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep emit
1789     21:44:47.635 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1       ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep emit
1790     21:44:47.636 [Thread-3                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
2695     21:44:48.541 [Thread-3                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
2695     21:44:48.541 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1          ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - original 0 | switchMap 0
2792     21:44:48.638 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1       ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep emit
2792     21:44:48.638 [Thread-4                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
3693     21:44:49.539 [Thread-4                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
3693     21:44:49.539 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1          ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - original 1 | switchMap 0
3796     21:44:49.642 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1       ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep emit
3797     21:44:49.643 [Thread-5                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
4699     21:44:50.545 [Thread-5                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
4699     21:44:50.545 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1          ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - original 2 | switchMap 0
4802     21:44:50.648 [Thread-6                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
5706     21:44:51.552 [Thread-6                        ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - sleep switch
5706     21:44:51.552 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1          ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - original 3 | switchMap 0
6612     21:44:52.458 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1          ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - original 3 | switchMap 1
6612     21:44:52.458 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1          ] DEBUG SwitchMapTest - complete
```