# Rxjs Observable Interval and Angular2 HTTP: wait for response

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, intervals

I'm trying to create a service that polls a log at given interval (every 5 seconds). I need to make an http GET call, but on slow connections and large logs, the `switchMap` cancels the previous pending request. Thus, I'm never getting the log as the request is being canceled.

```js
getLog(url:string):Observable<string> {
    return Observable
        .timer(0, 5000)
        .switchMap(() => this.get(url))
        .retryWhen(error => error.delay(5000))
        .map((res:Response) => res.text())
        .catch(e => {
            console.warn(e.toString());
            return Observable.from("");
        });
}
```

and `this.get(url)` is simply `get(url) {return this.http.get(url)}`.

I am seeking to keep the timer functionality, but to not trigger another http call until the previous call has resolved, and to not cancel the pending call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between flatmap and switchmap in RxJava?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175702/what-is-the-difference-between-flatmap-and-switchmap-in-rxjava)

Comment: To put it another way: use `flatMap` instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `flatMap` keeps creating new requests. I don't want to create new requests until the pending request has finished.

Comment: Oh, I thought the requests being cancelled was the problem; please [edit] to clarify the behaviour you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `concatMap()` instead of `switchMap()`.

As you said the `switchMap()` operator cancels the previous requests. The `flatMap()` (or `mergeMap()`) operator just creates another Observable and subscribes to all of them immediately.

On the other hand, the `concatMap()` operator waits until the previous Observable completes and then subscribes to the next Observable. So even if your timer is emitting faster than the requests are finished you'll always receive all their responses in the same order.