# RxJava2 idiom for combining two Maybes

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

Given two `Maybe` values, how can I combine them into a single `Maybe` that will either:

1. call `onSuccess()` whenever either of the source `Maybes` calls `onSuccess`
2. call `onComplete()` whenever *both* of the source `Maybes` call `onComplete()`?

(Cf. `Option.orElse()` in [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option.html#orElse[B%3E:A](alternative:=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]) or [Vavr](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Option.html#orElse-io.vavr.control.Option-).)

E.g., assuming the existence of a `combine()` method that does what I want:

```
combine(Maybe.just(a), Maybe.empty())  ≍ Maybe.just(a)
combine(Maybe.empty(), Maybe.just(b))  ≍ Maybe.just(b)
combine(Maybe.empty(), Maybe.empty())  ≍ Maybe.empty()
combine(Maybe.never(), /*anything*/ )  ≍ /*the thing*/ 
combine(/*anything*/,  Maybe.never())  ≍ /*the thing*/
```

At first I thought `amb()` & family were what I was looking for, but that completes as soon as either source `Maybe` completes, meaning if the first `Maybe` completes without a value, you never get the value from the second `Maybe`.

Right now I'm using

```
Maybe.mergeArray(m1, m2).firstElement()
```

which seems to do what I want, but I’m not certain it’s correct and I’m not certain it’s the cleanest way to do it. (For instance, if there’s some delay, will it call `onSuccess()` immediately when one or the other source does, or will it wait for both `onComplete()`s?)

Is this correct? Is there a more idiomatic approach?

---

**ETA:** I'm happy taking the first value; I don't need to wait for both to complete:

```
combine(Maybe.just(a), Maybe.just(b))  ≍ Maybe.just(/* a or b, don't care */)
```

(I can imagine situations in which I might prefer one or the other and want to indicate that by order of the arguments, but in that situation I suspect sequential would be better than parallel.)

Comment: I believe that a `zip` function will wait for a terminal event from all sources observables before emitting the results, if you want to wait for terminal event of all sources?

Comment: @MarkKeen I don't want to wait for a terminal event; if there's a value, I want to take whichever comes first.

Comment: A question is when `combine(just(a), never())`, answer in first code block is 'never()'. But in the edit you said you don't wait for complete, so it should be 'just(a)'. Your description is inconsistent.

Comment: @DeanXu That's a good point. I'll edit that section.

Comment: @DavidMoles Your approach is the best. The only thing is you can use `merge` rather than `mergeArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slightly different approach which might be a little nearer to your definition. This would be using [`Observable.switchMapMaybe()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#switchMapMaybe-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

> Maps the upstream items into `MaybeSources` and switches (subscribes) to the newer ones while disposing the older ones (and ignoring their signals) and emits the latest success value of the current one if available while failing immediately if this Observable or any of the active inner `MaybeSources` fail.

```
Observable.just(m1, m2).switchMapMaybe(m -> m).firstElement()
```

But the approach using `Maybe.mergeArray(m1, m2).firstElement()` should be sufficient as well. The `firstElement()` operator emits the first element emitted by the `mergeArray()` flowable. This one is unordered and thus there's no information about the completion of any of the maybes.

Comment: I think `mergeArray()` is more readable but it does seem (after reading [this answer on `switchMap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180793/27358); I think the `switchMapXXX` docs need a few more revisions) that `switchMapMaybe()` more precisely captures the intent.

Comment: I downvoted, because it doesn't satisfy condition 1. For example when `m1 = Maybe.just(1).delay(1, SECONDS)` and `m2 = Maybe.empty<Int>().delay(2, SECONDS)` it will call `onComplete` even though `m1` would call `onSuccess`