# RxJava2 how to update existing subscription when request parameter changes

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have an activity on which I make a network request everytime the user input changes.

The api definition is as follows:

```
interface Api {
  @GET("/accounts/check")
  fun checkUsername(@Query("username") username: String): Observable<UsernameResponse>
}
```

Then the services that manages it all:

```
class ApiService {

  var api: Api

  init {
    api = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
  }

  companion object {
    val baseUrl: String = "https://someapihost"
    var rxAdapter: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .build()


}

  fun checkUsername(username: String): Observable<UsernameResponse> {
    return api.checkUsername(username)
  }
}
```

Then inside my activity, whenever the EditText content changes, I make this call:

```
  private fun checkUsername(username: String) {
      cancelSubscription()
      checkUsernameDisposable = ApiService()
            .checkUsername(username)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
              updateUi(it)
      }
  }
```

So this is creating a new disposable every time the input changes. This is obviously incorrect. What I want to do is to update the existing subscription with the results of the new network call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you're thinking right, creating an `Observable` for each change event is far from efficient.

There are 2 approaches to this:

**One**

You can use [RxBinding](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/RxJava-and-RxBinding) to get a text change `Observable`, now you can `flatMap` the text changes to your apiService call, down to one disposable.

```
disposable = RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
    .switchMap { ApiService().checkUsername(it) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { updateUi(it) }
```

**Two**

You can use a `Subject` to use as a channel for the changes of the `EditText` like this:

```
val editTextChangesSubject: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create()

// when the editText changes call
editTextChangesSubject.onNext(newText)

disposable = editTextChangesSubject
        .switchMap { ApiService().checkUsername(it) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { updateUi(it) }
```

Now that's also down to one disposable!

Note: People sometimes tend to use the `Subject` technique if they're using a specific architecture pattern that separates the View logic from the middle man logic, if you're not bound by that, `RxBinding` is the way to go.

Also if worth mentioning, the two approaches will give you powers that didn't exist when subscribing for each text change event, like using flow control operators like `debounce` or `onBackpressureLatest`.

*Edit*:

Used `switchMap` instead of `flatMap`, see the difference in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175702/what-is-the-difference-between-flatmap-and-switchmap-in-rxjava)

Comment: You might want  to propose using the `switchMap()` operator instead of `flatMap()`. `switchMap()` will unsubscribe from the previous observable when it fires up the next observable.