# Inner map not getting called in Rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I've got this code which uses two pipes to load a product instance and its playlist. If there's an error when loading the playlist, the property is set to null:

```
getProduct(productId: number): Observable<ProductDTO> {
    return this.internalFindOne(productId).pipe(
      flatMap((productDTO: ProductDTO) => {
        return this.productPlaylistService.getProductPlaylist(productId).pipe(
          map((productPlaylistDTO: ProductPlaylistDTO) => {
            productDTO.playlist = productPlaylistDTO;
            return productDTO;
          }),
          catchError(() => {
            // If product playlist doesn't find anything, we still have to return the product dto object
            productDTO.playlist = null;
            return of(productDTO);
          }),
        );
      })
    );
}
```

It is already working this way. However, I don't think `flatMap` should fit here. There's no compiler error, but as far as I know `flatMap` works in a 1:n fashion, whereas `map` does it in a 1:1 [fashion](https://medium.com/@daveford/map-versup-flatmap-14780ab01d2b). My code is expecting a `productDTO` as an input here and returns the same `productDTO` modified. But when I replace the `flatMap` call by just `map`, the nested `map` function stops getting called (neither the success or the error parts).

`ProductDTO` and `ProductPlaylistDTO` are not iterable classes.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap)'s 'flat' prefix means that it flattens the observable it returns and as the result you'll get the returned observable data instead of the observable itself. It's like removing of one *level* of the nested observables. It works pretty similar to the [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap). You can read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28175702/4858777).

At the same time [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) just transforms the data, so if you return an observable from the `map()` you'll get this observable as the result:

```js
internalFindOne(productId).pipe(
  flatMap(() => {
    return getProductPlaylist(productId);
  }),
  tap((additionalData: ProductPlaylistDTO) => { ... })
);

internalFindOne(productId).pipe(
  map(() => {
    return getProductPlaylist(productId);
  }),
  tap((additionalData$: Observable<ProductPlaylistDTO>) => { ... })
);
```

But in your case, since these two requests don't depend on each other you can execute them simultaneously using [combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest):

```js
getProduct(productId: number): Observable<ProductDTO> {
  return combineLatest([
    this.internalFindOne(productId),
    this.productPlaylistService.productPlaylistService(productId).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of(null);
      })
    ),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([ product, playlist ]) => {
      product.playlist = playlist;
      return product;
    })
  );
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-1at8zf?embed=1&file=index.ts)

Comment: Good rewrite! It works.. However I would like to know what's going on with `flatMap` in my case :-(

Comment: @XtremeBiker I'm sorry, I had to explain the difference. I updated the answer, hope it helps you!